# White dots with purple background while Windows 10 is booting

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, visual-artifacts

I recently installed Windows 10, so I didn't update any drivers yet. While dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10 everything worked perfectly during installation. After a restart I can choose whether to boot Ubuntu or Windows. When I choose Windows I see screen with purple background with white dots on it for less than a minute and Windows starts normally, but it appears every time I boot Windows.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't Windows boot? That purple is normal to me as I see it everyday on my dual boot system!

Comment: Not just purple screen but with white dots everywhere in screen seems unusual !!

Comment: @bilal If you don't like purple color, you can change grub's color to black. ***white dots everywhere in screen:*** Can you please share a picture?

Comment: I try to upload the picture but I can't i just created the account now .

Comment: https://ibb.co/3CGvWV1

Comment: Yes, it's not normal, although seems harmless. I upvoted the question.

Comment: I've seen this on some systems with NVIDIA switchable graphics inside.. well any switchable graphics. It largely depends on the BIOS.

If you want to bypass booting windows via grub, you can manually select it in the boot selection on your laptop (typically F8).